# Google Cloud storage doesn't show the bucket in browser for a user who has access to it

Tags: google-cloud-storage

In our project, we have a group of people which should have full access to **ONLY a bucket** and they should not see other buckets or the object on the other buckets.
so, i changed the permission of the bucket, and i added the users as **Storage Admin** for that specific bucket (not for whole project).

In this case, when they use console/Storage they see the following message:
[image]

But when they open cloud Shell and they use **Gsutil**, they can access to the bucket objects (no access to other buckets).

Is this a bug on the interface of Console/storage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug, but it *is* a subtlety of the Console. In order to access a bucket from the Console, you typically navigate to it using the Browser, which is what appears you attempt in the screenshot. This fails, though, because to do this you need *[permission to list buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-console)* for a project, even if you otherwise have free reign to work within the bucket.

There are three ways to deal with this:

1) Give your users the *Viewer* permission for the project that contains the bucket. There are pros and cons to this. I'd say it's probably not worth going this route (though not as much because your users will see other buckets - [bucket namespace is publicly viewable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#naming) anyway - but because doing so brings up some [additional permission nuances](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/projects#permissions) you probably don't want to deal with).

2) Link directly to the desired bucket, thus avoiding the "listing buckets" portion of the Console. The URL for a bucket has the form: console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/[BUCKET_NAME]. I believe this will work without any additional modifications to your permissions.

3) Create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) that only contains the storage.buckets.list permission, and use that role on the project for affected users.

Comment: OP could indeed try using this. However, I think it should not be a problem of permissions, as [`storage.admin`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) grants the `storage.buckets.list` permissions for that project.

Comment: @Nathan : the first one is not a correct solution at all, because if i give them Viewer access for the project, they can go through the other buckets and download the files (they can not create folder or upload files on these buckets), this is what we should completely avoid as there are files with sensitive data!

Comment: @Yandrak3 - If the OP applied storage.admin to the entire project, that would be the case, however, when placed on an individual bucket (as I interpreted was done in the question), the storage.buckets.list permission has no effect.

Comment: @Majico - The first one will work since the intrinsic behavior of Viewer is only to list buckets, but requires additional work beyond simply applying Viewer, because there is modifiable behavior which, by default, allows Viewers to do more (which is why I said it probably wasn't worth going that route): you would need to also remove the Reader permission that gets applied via the default access control list as well as the legacyBucketViewer IAM role that gets applied to the project.

Comment: I realized there's a third option that's analogous to, but simpler than, the first. Have updated the answer above.

Comment: The third option with the custom role is definitely what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!